# Does windows Azure have Web Cache features?

Tags: caching, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to use a [web cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) for my api which is hosted in an Azure website.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you found so far browsing the available Azure services on azure.com?

Comment: Redis cache, managed cache...but I can't find anything that looks like web cache.

Answer (score 1):

you could implement this yourself within the api. you have not indicated how your api is developed, for asp.net web api, you could use, for example [cachecow](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekASPNETWebAPICachingWithCacheCowAndCacheOutput.aspx)

If you're looking to use an Azure service to do so outside your API - [Azure API Management](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management) has built-in response [caching capability](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-cache/)

Comment: Thanks Yossi..I'm using NancyFx. I will check out Azure API Management.